# Redgate and Jenkins

Tags: sql-server, jenkins, redgate, tsqlt

I installed Redgate on my SQL Server and at the same time I installed its plugin on Jenkins.

I wrote some tests for SQL Server using Redgate SQL Test and I am trying to run those tests on Jenkins. But the problem is that Jenkins gets the db schema but cannot reach the data. The test has a select data count from a table and it seems not visible to Jenkins and it can not compare the results.

Therefore the test fails in Jenkins.

I tried to use SQL Data Generator and let the plugin read from it. It did work but I need to use my real data.

Any Idea how to do it !?

Answer (score 2):

When using tSQLt you should be adding the test data in the test itself. This test data gets rolled back at the end of each test by tSQLt, resetting the state for the next test. Is there a reason why you're trying to use your own data set?

Comment: yes that's my problem , how to add the real Data , I mean the database data to the test ? @David Atkinson

Comment: Can you just put INSERTs at the top of each test?

Comment: This is my first time using both redgate test and Jenkins. The Test works perfect in sql server, but in Jenkins it doesnt find the data, what kind of INSERTs should I add ? Insert table or what exactly ?

Comment: Yes, you just add INSERT into <table> values (1,2,3) at the start of the test. Can you share your tsqlt test in your question?